# Sqlite Group By of subquery returns only one row

Tags: sqlite

We observed that Sqlite returns always only one row if we apply group on a subquery and do not use an aggregation operation such as count or sum.

Here is a toy example:

Given table

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 rank INT NOT NULL
);
```

with data

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable(id, rank) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO ExampleTable(id, rank) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO ExampleTable(id, rank) VALUES (3, 2);
```

the query

```
SELECT rank, COUNT(*) FROM (select id, rank from ExampleTable) GROUP BY rank;
```

returns

```
rank|count
2|2
1|1
```

However, without the COUNT operation Sqlite returns only 1 row.

```
SELECT rank FROM (select id, rank from ExampleTable) GROUP BY rank;
```

=>

```
rank
1
```

Is this is a bug or an expected behavior?

Comment: Works for me. Probably a bug in your old version.

Comment: I am using version 2.8.17. Which version did you use?

Comment: SQLite 2 was obsoleted ten years ago.